# How to write an image (should be exact size) to an external storage

Tags: java, android, image, file-handling

I am writing a program that reads the image from resource/drawable and flushes out to the external storage. My problem is that different devices consume different memory for the same image but, I need the memory consumption to be constant. For example device 1 shows the image size to be 3MB whereas device 2 shows the image size to be 4MB. Below is the sample code that I have.
TIA

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//setting few options
//making sure that the getByteCount will always return the same value irrespective of the device
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image, options); 
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream); //where outstream is where I need to store my image in the device filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that your devices have different screen sizes and density. Therefore different resources are used.

In order to get drawable for a specific screen size you can use the code below:

```
Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawableForDensity(id, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH, theme);
```

Furthermore, you can try to reduce the size of the image:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inSampleSize = 3; 
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.hqimage, options);
```

But generally, you cannot always be sure that the image will consume the same amount of memory, it depends on various factors.

Hope this helps.